# Can this program exit normally?

Tags: c, child-process

```
int ccount=0;
void child_handler(int sig){
int child_status;
pid_t pid = wait(&child_status);
ccount--;
}

void fork() {
pid_t pid[N];
int i, child_status;
ccount=N;
signal(SIGCHLD, child_handler);
for (i=0; i<N ; i++) {
    if ((pid[i]=fork())==0) {
        sleep(1); exit(0);
    }
while (ccount>0)  pause();
}
```

In this function, suppose that any one parent process receive the last SIGCHLD signal, Nth signal, between while and paust(). Then it cannot exit() because it cannot escape from while loop. 
Then can I say that this program exits unnormally?

Comment: `void fork()` and `pid[i]=fork()` - your `fork` does not return a value.

Comment: You need to rename your function `fork` to something else.

Comment: void fork() or void main() ?

Comment: Maybe you can use the shell command "echo $?" to check it. If it returns 0, then we say it exit "normally."